# Passing a variable from PHP to jQuery on page load

Tags: php, jquery, variables

I'm trying to take a reference variable from the url, and query my database when the user first visits the page. 
I then need to take this results and plot on google maps.

```
<?php 
    include('storelocator/db/config.php');
    include('storelocator/db/db.php');  

    if(isset($_GET['ref'])){

        $ref = stripslashes($_GET['ref']);

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `markers` WHERE `ref` = \"".$_GET['ref']."\"";

        $result = mysql_query($sql);    
        $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
        print_r($row);
    }
?>
```

This is my code at the top of my index page, it works fine, the print_r gives the correct results. I'm just not sure how to pass these results to jQuery to be plotted. (I know how to plot, I basically need to know how to pass a variable $row['latlng'] to jQuery.)

thanks

Comment: thanks for the quick replies. echoing out the variable works, I'm wondering if this considered bad practise, because now my page begins with a <script> element.

Comment: The obvious answer is to do the "echoing" in the appropriate place in your document

Comment: makes sense. Brains clearly not turned on today, cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var markers = <?php echo json_encode($row) ?>;
</script>
```

Now the `markers` JavaScript variable will be available to any scripts following the above.

You can access associative entries from the PHP `$row` array using

```
var latlng = markers.latlng;
```

While we're here, you should protect your query from SQL injection. Whilst I always recommend using PDO and parameter binding, a quick fix for you would be

```
$ref = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($_GET['ref']) : $_GET['ref'];
$sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM `markers` WHERE `ref` = '%s'",
               mysql_real_escape_string($ref));
```

Comment: +1 for using json_encode which takes care of escaping special characters.

Answer (score 1):

In line with

```
print_r($row);
```

put:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
echo 'var latlng = "' . $row['latlng'] . '";';
echo '</script>';
```

This is the way to pass data to JavaScript. ;)

Answer (score 0):

the following code pass your data to the javascript variable: 'data'

```
echo "<script>var data='".$row['latlng']."';</script>"
```