# Php to Jquery Variable

Tags: php, jquery, variables

I have this in my `config.php` file

```
     $DOMAIN = 'http://domain.com';
 $DOMAIN_SSL = 'http://domain.com';
$DOMAIN_ROOT = 'var/domain/root/html';
```

`config.php` is included in each page on first line

Now I have this jQuery code

```
var country = '<?php echo $_GET['country'];?>'; 
var category = 'Cat' ;
var category = '<?php echo $DOMAIN.'/link'; ?>';
```

How can I get variables from php with jQuery code to make jQuery code like this

```
var country = '$country'; 
var category = 'Cat' ;
var url= '$domain','/link';
```

ORIGINAL CODE
I NEED TO EXLUDE PHP

```
var country = '<?php echo $_GET['country'];?>'; 
                var category = 'CAT1' ;               
                function loadData(page){
                    loading_show();                    
                    $.ajax
                    ({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "<?php echo $DOMAIN ?>/post.php",
                        data: "page="+page +"&category="+category+"&country="+country,
                        success: function(msg)
                        {
                        loading_hide();
                        $("#content-large").html(msg);
                        }
                    });
                }
                loadData(1);  // For first time page load default results
                $('#content-large .pagination li.active').live('click',function(){
                    var page = $(this).attr('p');
                    loadData(page);

                });           
                $('#go_btn').live('click',function(){
                    var page = parseInt($('.goto').val());
                    var no_of_pages = parseInt($('.total').attr('a'));
                    if(page != 0 && page <= no_of_pages){
                        loadData(page);
                    }else{
                        alert('Enter a PAGE between 1 and '+no_of_pages);
                        $('.goto').val("").focus();
                        return false;
                    }

                });
            });
```

Comment: I don't really get your problem, the above seems to do what you want?

Comment: Since you didn't accept my answer, I'm really lost on what you actually wanted. Could you somehow clarify? Did you want to load the values from the file straight (with an AJAX call)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6188062/passing-a-variable-from-php-to-jquery-on-page-load?

Comment: This new edit makes it look like something that's not gonna happen unless you echo everything.

Comment: If you're doing it like that, why not just store $_GET['country'] in a cookie or session on this page and use that in the next PHP file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Updated Answer

If you're attempting to get values from the URL, much like you would using `$_GET` in PHP, I would encourage you to use something like the jQuery URL Parser:

```
var country = $.url().param("country"); // Gets the 'country' parameter
```

Download jQuery URL Parser: https://github.com/allmarkedup/jQuery-URL-Parser

#### Original Answer

I would encourage you to keep it simple; just use formatted strings and `json_encode`. For example:

```
$country  = "United States";
$domain   = "http://stackoverflow.com";
$category = 5;

printf( "var country  = %s;", json_encode( $country ) );
printf( "var category = %s;", json_encode( $category ) );
printf( "var domain   = %s;", json_encode( $domain . "/link" ) );
```

Which outputs:

```
var country  = "United States";
var category = 5;
var domain   = "http:\/\/stackoverflow.com\/link";
```

Comment: That nice  i get the country variables from get

Comment: @RobertMrsic Where would you like to use that?

Comment: Yes but the problem ist that you use allvays php i need exlude php code why when i use comiler i get allvays error

Comment: @Robert Mrsic: You...don't wanna use PHP because you have errors in your code? Then you'll need to [parse the URL using Javascript](http://www.webdevelopmentcentral.net/2006/06/parsing-url-variables-with-javascript.html).

Comment: @RobertMrsic You can assign `$country = $_GET['country'];` if you want. Just be careful the types of data you let people embed in your page via the URL.

Comment: no the code work perfect the problem ist when i go to compress jquery with google compiler i get allvays erorr

Comment: i dont have errors ,the errors are php for jquery compiler not for script

Comment: @RobertMrsic Don't compress the PHP version. If you want to compress your JavaScript, you do so *after* PHP has processed its values.

Comment: @Jonathan Have the server send the PHP result file to Google and request it back compressed to then send it on to the client? Does Google even offer that kind of thing?

Comment: The problem ist that i have many pages with this script if i find way how to exlude php i cann add it to external .js and at whell compress it

Comment: @Armatus I'm not encouraging that. You can however do compression on your own server, without using a service like Google. That would be more in line with what I'm suggesting.

Comment: @RobertMrsic I've updated the answer to include a jQuery plugin that will help you grab values from the URL. Hope this helps.

Comment: NO sorry for my english ist not so good and i have problem to explain it as well but here ist  google compiler

Comment: @RobertMrsic Please see my update and let me know if it helps you. Additionally, feel free to post a comment in your native language asking your question - perhaps somebody can offer a translation.

Comment: http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home If i put there compete script code i get error

Comment: PERFECT Its work with url parser `var country = $.url().param("country");`

Comment: Now just remain the problem how i get $DOMAIN with jquery

Comment: @RobertMrsic `var domain = $.url().attr("host");` I believe. Be sure to study the jQuery URL Parser [examples and documentation](https://github.com/allmarkedup/jQuery-URL-Parser).

Comment: Sorry i not need it in var i need exlude php from here: "url: "<?php echo $DOMAIN ?>/post.php","

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is on the page and not in some separate JS file, you could just write the entire statement in PHP.

```
<?php echo "var country = " . json_encode($_GET['country']) . ";"; ?>
```

Comment: You're mixing up syntax, the concat operator in PHP is `.` not `+`. You're also missing quotes.

Comment: You need quotes around the country string.  That will end up with something like `var country = Brasil;`

Comment: Whoops. I haven't been writing in PHP very often apparently. Thanks for the save. And the quotes are just my own mistake...

Comment: The problem ist that i not need to use php but only javascript

Comment: Ugh, you should really use `json_encode` to ensure you get a valid JS string.

Comment: @Mizuho When using `json_encode()`, you don't need to provide your own quotes around the value - it will do this for you when the value type requires them.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, I think you don't need to overcomplicate things here so much. This may not be the fanciest solution or anything but it should work.

The idea is, on the actual page (say, `home.php`) you would echo an HTML element containing the values you need, such as:

```
//Fill this array with all the values that you want available in JS
$JSONarray = array('all'=>'the','values'=>'you','want'=>'in','JS');
//Later print it on the page
echo "<span class='hidden' id='transferred_values'>"
    .json_encode($JSONarray)."</span>";
```

(Side note: you would set the class "hidden" to be invisible to the user.)

Now your external JS (say, `scripts.js`) can retrieve the values using JS only which will allow you to use the compressor:

```
$(function(){
    var transfer = $.parseJSON( $('#transferred_values').text() );
});
```

Let me know if this violates good practice or any rules I'm not aware of :)

Comment: IMO it does violate good practice, because it creates needless HTML nodes.

Comment: Some people need to store JavaScript templates, and to avoid another AJAX/AHAH call they either store them like you did in a hidden div, or (better) in an HTML comment. Because HTML comments are nodes too, and they are retrievable from JavaScript.

Comment: Well, it would be one additional node (plus a few subnotes), so the impact should be around as large as the difference between single and double quotes in PHP. I didn't know you could use comments, but it sounds like an interesting approach.

Comment: It's more elegant when it comes to HTML, less elegant when it comes to JS usage. Either way my opinion wasn't that it adds complexity, just that it's less semantic and less elegant as grabbing the template(s) remotely via AHAH.